# UIView background color with alpha in xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib

I have a problem. I am trying to make my custom UIView with an image in the very center. The part outside of that image got to be transparent and grayed. 
In xib for "View" I've set this:[image: My View's settings in xib]

The result - fail. The region outside the image is just gray, not transparent.
But if I add

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
  self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
}
```

Then everything works as expected.
What was I doing wrong when trying to achieve transparent backround in xib?

UPDATE:
I found the code which was doing presenting of the view, and there was alpha set inside of it. So I guess that was the problem. Thanks. Sorry for being so newbie

Comment: Are you sure it's not working?  Perhaps a light gray color with an alpha of 0.75 doesn't have that much of a visual affect.  Try just like you did in your code: a black color with 0.5 alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in custom show method. It didn't use **presentViewController:animated:completion:** method. It used alpha animaiton from 0 to 1. The second - when using standard **presentViewController:animated:completion:** method cocoa optimization was hiding the underlying view, so I need to set up (for iOS 8)

```
vc_to_present_on.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
vc_to_be_presented.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

And then everything work as expected

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this one is what you expected. You can only change the background Color rather the view's alpha. Just set `opacity` with the background Color.

[image]

Comment: Great! This provide to set UIView background with transparency and without transparency inheritance!

Answer (score 2):

When setting the alpha of a parent UIView, the alpha value will be passed to the child views, giving the same alpha to all the child views. If you set the alpha value of the UIView to 1, you are setting the alpha of the view, not the color.

That said, you can set the alpha of the background color. When you do this, the view maintains its own alpha value, while the background color has its own alpha value. Hope this helps